# php curl get documents content

Tags: php, json, curl

How to get the all the content using **curl**  and **jsonblob**.

So what i have done is that i have upload  a JSON file in jsonblob, and now i am trying to get all those data's.

So i am trying to get those contents like so in PHP---

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://jsonblob.com/5621c1f2e4b01190df3c0dc5" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Accept: application/json'));
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 
var_dump($result);
```

> Output -bool(true)

But i want all the contents not just the check.

Do anyone knows how i can get all the contents!

Comment: They have an API for this sort of thing... - [`Jsonblob API - GET`](https://jsonblob.com/api#get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set cUrl option to return content before run curl_exec():

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
```

Regards,